# How to display "only" word after the num value converted in to in word

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function onlyNumbers(evt) {
  var e = event || evt; // For trans-browser compatibility
  var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;

  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    return false;
  return true;
}

function NumToWord(inputNumber, outputControl) {
  var str = new String(inputNumber)
  var splt = str.split("");
  var rev = splt.reverse();
  var once = ['Zero', ' One', ' Two', ' Three', ' Four', ' Five', ' Six', ' Seven', ' Eight', ' Nine'];
  var twos = ['Ten', ' Eleven', ' Twelve', ' Thirteen', ' Fourteen', ' Fifteen', ' Sixteen', ' Seventeen', ' Eighteen', ' Nineteen'];
  var tens = ['', 'Ten', ' Twenty', ' Thirty', ' Forty', ' Fifty', ' Sixty', ' Seventy', ' Eighty', ' Ninety'];

  numLength = rev.length;
  var word = new Array();
  var j = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < numLength; i++) {
    switch (i) {

      case 0:
        if ((rev[i] == 0) || (rev[i + 1] == 1)) {
          word[j] = '';
        } else {
          word[j] = '' + once[rev[i]];
        }
        word[j] = word[j];
        break;

      case 1:
        aboveTens();
        break;

      case 2:
        if (rev[i] == 0) {
          word[j] = '';
        } else if ((rev[i - 1] == 0) || (rev[i - 2] == 0)) {
          word[j] = once[rev[i]] + " Hundred ";
        } else {
          word[j] = once[rev[i]] + " Hundred and";
        }
        break;

      case 3:
        if (rev[i] == 0 || rev[i + 1] == 1) {
          word[j] = '';
        } else {
          word[j] = once[rev[i]];
        }
        if ((rev[i + 1] != 0) || (rev[i] > 0)) {
          word[j] = word[j] + " Thousand";
        }
        break;


      case 4:
        aboveTens();
        break;

      case 5:
        if ((rev[i] == 0) || (rev[i + 1] == 1)) {
          word[j] = '';
        } else {
          word[j] = once[rev[i]];
        }
        if (rev[i + 1] !== '0' || rev[i] > '0') {
          word[j] = word[j] + " Lakh";
        }

        break;

      case 6:
        aboveTens();
        break;

      case 7:
        if ((rev[i] == 0) || (rev[i + 1] == 1)) {
          word[j] = '';
        } else {
          word[j] = once[rev[i]];
        }
        if (rev[i + 1] !== '0' || rev[i] > '0') {
          word[j] = word[j] + " Crore";
        }
        break;

      case 8:
        aboveTens();
        break;



      default:
        break;
    }
    j++;
  }

  function aboveTens() {
    if (rev[i] == 0) {
      word[j] = '';
    } else if (rev[i] == 1) {
      word[j] = twos[rev[i - 1]];
    } else {
      word[j] = tens[rev[i]];
    }
  }

  word.reverse();
  var finalOutput = '';
  for (i = 0; i < numLength; i++) {
    finalOutput = finalOutput + word[i];
  }

  document.getElementById(outputControl).innerHTML = finalOutput;

}
```

```css
input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

.num-disp-bg {
  font-size: 13;
  color: #444444;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Amount in Figures</label>
    <div class="input-group">

      <input type="number" id="number" class="form-control" style="width:75%;" placeholder="Enter Amount" value="" onkeypress="return onlyNumbers(this.value);" onkeyup="NumToWord(this.value,'divDisplayWords');" required>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Amount in Words</label>

    <div class="num-disp-bg form-control" id="divDisplayWords"></div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Hi I have done all the code for converting the num value in to the word (figure). Only after the insert numeric value in input field the number should convert in to word and display as in div. Figure of amount will shown accurately but "Only" word is not getting display i have try many time but did not get proper way. How do i do this can you please help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... So you've written all this rather complex yet apparently working code all by yourself, but now you're stuck at appending "Only" onto the final result? Unless I misunderstood your issue?

Comment: thanks for your comment i got solution. more after the amount in figure display i want Only word. Like "Ten Thousand Two Hundred Only", currently it is displaying like this "Ten Thousand Two Hundred".

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.getElementById(outputControl).innerHTML = finalOutput + " only";
```